# Make a stacked area chart where each group is neatly on top of one another

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data frame is below. I'm trying to create a stacked area chart where each group is stacked one on top of the other.

Here's the mess I'm currently grasping at straws with:

```
example_df %>% group_by(NEW_REG_DATE, CARD_TYPE) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = NEW_REG_DATE, y = Count, fill = CARD_TYPE, group = CARD_TYPE)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 2), fun.y = sum, geom = 'line', size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%b", date_breaks = "1 week", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1), legend.position = "bottom")
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Note how it appears as though the groups are overlapping and it's hard to distinguish each group. I would like them stacked neatly on top of each other. How can I do that?

Here is the data:

```
example_df <- structure(list(NEW_REG_DATE = structure(c(16806, 16792, 16792, 
16802, 16826, 16882, 16779, 16783, 16876, 16779, 16822, 16835, 
16802, 16815, 16823, 16867, 16801, 16872, 16800, 16823, 16868, 
16792, 16779, 16853, 16773, 16877, 16820, 16866, 16783, 16779, 
16835, 16832, 16847, 16870, 16872, 16847, 16862, 16854, 16792, 
16893, 16781, 16812, 16816, 16851, 16791, 16867, 16771, 16865, 
16785, 16857, 16787, 16813, 16830, 16849, 16785, 16873, 16856, 
16770, 16810, 16822, 16782, 16877, 16841, 16777, 16865, 16841, 
16830, 16827, 16789, 16850, 16768, 16796, 16784, 16785, 16784, 
16831, 16815, 16853, 16845, 16865, 16770, 16878, 16878, 16789, 
16788, 16796, 16791, 16808, 16814, 16853, 16792, 16820, 16785, 
16770, 16847, 16772, 16810, 16864, 16810, 16800, 16822, 16861, 
16830, 16775, 16810, 16822, 16771, 16826, 16773, 16886, 16777, 
16779, 16867, 16866, 16814, 16859, 16775, 16791, 16809, 16808, 
16871, 16774, 16868, 16791, 16792, 16835, 16848, 16787, 16877, 
16783, 16775, 16822, 16788, 16793, 16793, 16790, 16802, 16796, 
16820, 16779, 16810, 16866, 16783, 16842, 16785, 16772, 16821, 
16794, 16779, 16862, 16802, 16877, 16798, 16802, 16787, 16862, 
16877, 16812, 16800, 16787, 16826, 16868), class = "Date"), CARD_TYPE = c("Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Adult", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Adult", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Adult", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Adult", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Adult", "Youth", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", "Youth", 
"Youth", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent", 
"Youth with Parent", "Youth", "Youth with Parent")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-162L), .Names = c("NEW_REG_DATE", "CARD_TYPE"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is expected to work, but apparently the problem is a large number of missing `(NEW_REG_DATE, CARD_TYPE)` combinations in the data. Below I use `tidyr` to add those missing combinations with `Count` as zero:

```
library(tidyr)
example_df$CARD_TYPE <- factor(example_df$CARD_TYPE)
example_df %>% group_by(NEW_REG_DATE, CARD_TYPE) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  complete(NEW_REG_DATE, CARD_TYPE, fill = list(Count = 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = NEW_REG_DATE, y = Count)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = CARD_TYPE), alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 2), fun.y = sum, geom = 'line', size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%b", date_breaks = "1 week", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, actually I'm getting an error message " Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the code in my answer? If not, then hard to say, sounds like too many aesthetics somewhere.

Comment: Adding group = CARD_TYPE into the aes solved it for me. Thanks a lot for the answer I was really spinning my wheels with this one

Comment: I'm just curious, why did we need to convert to factor? I mean it works... but don't get it? Factors is one part of r that just never seem to click with me

Comment: It is for `complete`. Without converging to factor it does nothing. I also find it somewhat strange but `?complete` mentions that. It's not necessary for the plotting part.